# Spring Boot Weblogic Deployment

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, weblogic

I am trying to deploy a spring boot app (2.2.5.RELEASE) in weblogic 12.2.1.4.0.
The app starts up correctly. However, whenever I am tyring to save or update something nothing is getting commited. After messing around a bit with different configurations I am at a point that whenever I am trying to commit something I get an error:

```
org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a timeout); nested exception is weblogic.transaction.RollbackException: setRollbackOnly called on transaction
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:631)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:385)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
    at gr.sigmasoft.gr.service.UserDataService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e4b5f55d.save(<generated>)
    at gr.sigmasoft.gr.web.rest.UserDataResource.createUserData(UserDataResource.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:920)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
```

If I run the app with the integrated tomcat everything commits and works perfectly.

My weblogic.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wls:weblogic-web-app
xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web- app_2_5.xsdc-web-app"  metadata-complete="true">
<wls:weblogic-version>12.2.1.4.0</wls:weblogic-version>
<wls:container-descriptor>
    <wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>false</wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>
</wls:container-descriptor>
<wls:context-root>/context</wls:context-root>
<wls:container-descriptor>
    <wls:prefer-application-packages>
        <wls:package-name>org.springframework.*</wls:package-name>

        <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.codehaus.stax2.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>com.google.common.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.bouncycastle.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>javax.persistence.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>javassist</wls:package-name>


        <!--Add Application Provided Validation Library-->

        <wls:package-name>javax.validation.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>javax.validation.BootstrapConfiguration</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>javax.validation.bootstrap.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>javax.validation.constraints.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>javax.validation.groups.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>javax.validation.metadata.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>javax.validation.spi.*</wls:package-name>


        <!--Add Application Provided Hibernate Library-->
        <wls:package-name>org.hibernate.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.hibernate.ejb.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.hibernate.jpa.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.hibernate.validator.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.hibernate.validator.internal.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.*</wls:package-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    <wls:prefer-application-resources>
        <wls:resource-name>org.springframework.*</wls:resource-name>
        <wls:resource-name>javax.persistence.*</wls:resource-name>
        <wls:resource-name>javax.validation.BootstrapConfiguration</wls:resource-name>
        <wls:resource-name>org.hibernate.*</wls:resource-name>
        <wls:resource-name>org.hibernate.jpa.*</wls:resource-name>
        <wls:resource-name>META-INF/services/org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</wls:resource-name>

        <wls:resource-name>META-INF/services/javax.validation*</wls:resource-name>

    </wls:prefer-application-resources>
</wls:container-descriptor>
```

and my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><persistence version="2.2"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">

<persistence-unit name="default" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

    <description>
        Default configuration for persistence in weblogic
    </description>

    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.jcache.internal.JCacheRegionFactory"/>
        <property name="hibernate.javax.cache.provider" value="org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider"/>
        <property name="hibernate.ddl-auto" value="none" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false"/>

        <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransactionFactory"/>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.WeblogicJtaPlatform"/>

        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//xxxxxx/xxx"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="xxxx"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="xxxxx"/>

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

If you guys need any more information about the project structure or about the configurations let me know in order to update the question.
I have also, checked the weblogic configuration for when the transactions timeout, it is set to 600 second. The trasanction fails almost immediately.

Comment: Why are you using a `persistence.xml` with Spring Boot, and is there any possibility of not using external Weblogic for new Boot applications and going with the self-contained application jar instead?

Comment: Check the below two options :

`1. Go to admin console. Click on Servers. Click on configuration. In the tuning tab Set the stuck Thread Max time  to 300/600 like that. `  
`2. Option 2... Increase the JTA timeout from weblogic admin console to say 300.`

Comment: I'm not a spring expert but I think that if you use a spring context you should configure the correct Transaction Manager, disabling the Weblogic Conteiner JTA Manager and enabling the Spring JTA Manager.

Comment: @SimoneCasamassa can you provide me with some instructions or links on how to do so?

Comment: @Som Both of them are set to 600.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- the only  reason I am using the persitence.xml is to try and overcome the problems mentioned above. Unfortunately no, because the client wants to run the app inside weblogic for some reason.

Comment: You can search "WebLogicJtaTransactionManager" here: "https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/programming/spring.html"